# Is it safe to upload files in a folder on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple query hope it doesn't sound stupid but just wanting to know of it. I have build site with a module where you upload files (Photos, docx, xlxs, pdf etc) which goes inside the server folder and the datas and links goes into the sqlserver database. Now what I want to know are those files inside the server folder safe or if can anyone hack the server and go inside the folder and wipe away all the files? Really wanting know of it, please share your experience.

Comment: In general the answer would be, no they are not safe. You need to provide a  lot more information about your particular setup, application, environment to fully reason about your particular situation - probably more information than is a good fit for a question here. Try to identify smaller issues / questions you may have and provide more information about them.

Comment: @Christian.K Okay, I am sorry if my question are not relevant and sorry if I am unable to meet the standard of questioning, as I have just begin. Actually I have a site with .net framework build of C# and got domain purchased and hosted my site, where when I upload a photo from the module I built, the photos goes inside the folder in the server where I have hosted my site and the details about the photos and url link to retrieve the photo goes inside the sqlserver database. So just want to know if it is safe and if it is not what is the other way to keep it safe.

Comment: @Christian.K one more thing when we upload a photo in facebook how is it saved? does it get encrypted and goes inside the database? or how is it done?

Comment: Always assume there is a chance your files can be wiped, stolen or corrupted. You -must- have backups of your important photos, docx etc. so that you can restore them when needed. If you need to protect the file contents from prying eyes, use a proper level of encryption.

Comment: If somebody hacks your server then they can do pretty much anything with it...

Comment: As for your question regarding Facebook, check this eight year old link to get an idea of what they're doing: https://code.facebook.com/posts/685565858139515/needle-in-a-haystack-efficient-storage-of-billions-of-photos/

Comment: Wow ! 2009 is "old". I am getting older ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your question on how to upload/save/receive a photo:**

- In your view, you'll want to use the input file HTML object:

  < input type="file" id="image" name="image" >
- The user is going to click on the file upload button and select a local file to upload. So, you'll need to then receive that image through a request using a controller method in your server side code:

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult GetImageRequest()
  {
      HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files["image"];
      if (hpf != null && hpf.ContentLength > 0)
      {
          using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(hpf.InputStream))
          {
              byte[] imageFile = 
                 binaryReader.ReadBytes(hpf.ContentLength);
          }

          UploadImage(imageFile);                
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  ```
- Next, you'll send the byte array of the image (byte[] imageFile) to another method where the upload process will actually take place. You can upload it to a database table (data type for the DB object will be *varbinary(MAX)*). You can also upload it to an accessible folder on your web server. For uploading to my web server I tend to use FileStream.